# Add asp imagebutton inside javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to add asp image button inside a javascript function. Actually I need to create image buttons inside a html table dynamically. Here is my code. I need to add the image button where I have mentioned as "--- Here I need to add the image button ---"

```
function tableSeats() {
  document.write("<table align=center>");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

      document.write("<tr height=30px>");

      for (var r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
          document.write("<td width=30px>");
          document.write(--- Here I need to add the image button ---);
          document.write("</td>");
      }

      document.write("</tr>");
  }
  document.write("</table>");
}
```

If this is not possible, please tell me a way to do it using c#.net
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I believe by using javaScript you are not able to create any kind of server controls like image button and all. But you can do some kind of things like `<img />` And using jQuery you can invoke the client click and using ajax you can easily communicate with server.

```
function tableSeats() {

  document.write("<table align=center>");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

      document.write("<tr height=30px>");

      for (var r = 1; r <= 10; r++) {
          document.write("<td width=30px>");
          document.write("<img src='Your picture path' alt='' />");
          document.write("</td>");
      }

      document.write("</tr>");
  }
  document.write("</table>");
}
```

Updated the code

Check this for jQuery click
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: It is possible in C# .why you need C# ? this can be achievable using js and C# requires a page load etc. Here you can easily manipulate the controls using js and jquery, but you must have a server side validation to verify the data